# When was a file introduced into a given Git branch?

Tags: git, github, merge, git-log

We use Git and Github. We have two main branches, `staging` and `production`. When a new project/feature is assigned to a developer they create a new branch, call it `feature-branch` from `production`, make their changes, commit, push to GitHub, and merge `feature-branch` with `staging` using GitHub. When the feature is ready to go live, the developer then merges `feature-branch` with `production` using GitHub. All merges add a `merge` commit.

What happened was that a developer said their `feature-branch` contents were on `production` and they never performed a merge from `feature-branch` to `production`. It is possible that someone may have merged `staging` with `production` accidentally.

Some developers make mistakes and I'm trying to figure out the root at where it happened and possibly reverse it properly. I was hoping someone could help me out.

What I'm trying to do using a combination of GitHub, Git Bash and Git Extensions is find out at what point did a particular file enter a branch. Using Git Extensions `file history` feature it only shows when it's changes were committed, not necessarily when it was merged into a branch.

How can I accomplish this? I've searched and used many tactics to find file logs, like `git log --pretty=online <branch> -- <file>` found at [When was a file added to a branch in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848348/when-was-a-file-added-to-a-branch-in-git).

Any extra help would be appreciated. Please let me know if you need more information and I'll be happy to provide.

### Update #1

I forgot to mention this, which is probably important in this scenario. On `feature-branch` some changes (`change-1` and `change-2`) were committed and merged to both `staging` and `production`. The developer then made further changes (`changes-3`) to his `feature-branch` and only merged to `staging`. While `production` should have `change-1` and `change-2` and not `change-3`, how can I find out at what point `changes-3` made it's way into `production`?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475448/find-merge-commit-which-include-a-specific-commit) help?

Answer (score 3):

> What I'm trying to do [...] is find out at what point did a particular file enter a branch.

One issue with the problem statement is that files can be renamed, and if you simply run something like

```
git log --pretty=online <branch> -- <file>
```

only commits in which the file in question was called `<file>` will be listed. However, the `git log` flag called `--follow` is right up your alley; see the [`git-log` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

> `--follow`
>
> Continue listing the history of a file beyond renames (works only for a single
>   file).

Here you want to run

```
git log --reverse --follow <branch> -- <file-in-question>
```

The top log entry will corresponds to the *oldest* (in the chronological sense) commit in which `<file-in-question>` appears. If you want to get the *oldest* (in the topological sense) commit in which `<file-in-question>` appears, you need to add the `--topo-order` flag to the command above.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me about the `--follow` argument. However, the last commit does not seem to be the commit at which the file was introduced to the branch. Good catch concerning the file renamed situation. The commit given from the command above is the commit at which the file was renamed. I just realized I left out a piece of info and will add it as `update#1` above. it might make a difference.

Answer (score -1):

`git blame <filename>`
will give you line by line details of file with commit id and commiter name and datetime.

Comment: Thanks. However, this only shows on which commit each line was committed. I'm trying to find out when, commit bdc45b, was merged into the `production` branch.